# ImportError: cannot import name 'HuggingFaceInferenceAPI' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location)

Tags: python, machine-learning, langchain, huggingface, llama-index

want to import HuggingFaceInferenceAPI.

```
from llama_index.llms import HugggingFaceInferenceAPI
```

llama_index.llms documentation doesn't have HugggingFaceInferenceAPI module. Anyone has update on this?